# Can't move tabs in PHP Storm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to drag navigation tabs to new positions (and also to a different screen) in the editor in PHP Storm - I used to be able to do it but now it won't let me.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm on the EAP and have been switching between that and the stable release.

[edit] I've gone in to preferences/settings and checked tab-related settings, so far no joy.

Comment: What are "navigation tabs"? Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: In the editor, these are the tabs along the top for each file you are editing. Dragging one to a new screen should create a new editor window there.

Comment: Yes, that works for me. I can't reproduce. Search for a setting you may have accidentally set.

Comment: Yup, I've gone in to preferences and used 'tab' as the search string, played with those settings but no joy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem, and for me it was "Drag-n-drop with alt pressed only". Had to turn it off. You can search for it with just "ALT"[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I ended up saving my config, resetting to default and re-importing a bit at a time .. your way is much better :)

Comment: Hmph.  And I had turned this on _on purpose_ and forgot!  We'll see which way I prefer it (I was accidentally dragging tabs all over the place before)...

Comment: As a side (and late) note, remember that this also applies to moving files and directories locally AND on the server. I really *cannot* disable this option, it's too dangerous :-)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still experiences this problem - the most common reason of being unable to change order of tabs by drag and drop is having one of Tab Order options enabled. Here is where it sits:

[image]